# Problems with android GridView

Tags: android

I am trying to display 2 columns of text in a GridView in android. I create a TextView for each cell of the grid.  Everything seems to work well until the TextView tries to wrap the text to a second (or more) line.  When this happens, sometimes the second line of text overwrites the next cell, rather than causing the cell to expand to fit the text.  All I have to do to get the text to display properly is click one of the cells in the grid.  This seems to cause the grid to repaint and then everything gets displayed properly.  I have tried any number of things to fix this problem but nothing seems to help.

Is there some property that I have to set on the TextView or the GridView to allow the cells to expand to fit the text?  Or is this just a glitch in GridView that I have to live with?

BTW, setting android:singleLine="true" prevents the word wrap and solves the problem but it isn't an ideal solution because I really don't want the text to be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, I'm afraid you might have to do a work-around. I know it seems like a glitch, but it may be more ideal to continue to have your views start a consistent location instead of constantly having them shift based on content. I know this is a pain for what you're trying to do, but keep in mind that this was designed for hopefully the best solution for any application. Anyway..

One workaround I would propose might be manually updating the beginning of the views that get written over. I know it's not exactly ideal, but you can figure out where to place it based on the properties of your view. This doesn't feel like a particularly elegant solution though, so I'll try to cook something better up and/or post sample code. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I'm not sure how I would "update the beginning of the views that get written over".  The rendering is all done by the GridView component and I have no control over it.  Unless there is some functionality in GridView that I don't know about.

Comment: Further research has led me to believe that I want to be using ListView for this anyway.  It gives me much more control over the layout without a big increase in complexity.